# Data recovery from older session

Tags: data-recovery

I am using Ubuntu with VMware.

I am unable to login using my password.
I have tried multiple times but could not login.

Now, I have created another virtual machine.
But,I need to access the data from the machine,which I am not able to login.

What can I do now?

Comment: How exactly are you trying to log in and what happens when you do?